# Date Picker Not Working - xPages Mobile Form Domino 9 / Domino 8.5.3 with Extension Library

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Date picker not working properly in Domino 9 xPages Single page application. It shows 3 fields and display calendar in bottom of the form on mobile form on any device.
Please help

[image]

Hi, I have use this with the same code, Notes version and library but it is not showing correctly as specified in blue mix example. I will provide screen shot for the result. Is any "dojo" to be added on xpages?

Comment: You need to elaborate on server version (including fix packs), mobile devices tried, whether it's worked before, whether XPages demo applications have been tried. It's worth also including code and a screenshot. iOS mobile has certain Dojo requirements. Also, personally, I would not use a date picker on mobile devices. Other mobile web applications tend to use three separate comboboxes to select day, month and year. That seems to be a more appropriate approach for mobile apps.

Comment: Server version- Domino 9.0.1 FP3, Mobile Device - Android. Tried in xPage Singlepage application.

Comment: You mention in the title that you have the XPages Extension Library installed. What version?

Comment: I had Extension Library R14 installed

Answer (score 2):

I put up a [test app on Bluemix](http://mobile-date-test.mybluemix.net/SO32990114.nsf/m_datePicker.xsp) using single page application, with one appPage containing a datePicker.
All works well in Android Firefox, Android Chrome & default HTC Android browser (using Android 5, aka Lollipop). That app is using the XPages runtime on Bluemix, which contains 901FP4 & Extlib r13.

XPage code (m_datePicker.xsp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
  <xe:singlePageApp selectedPageName="dateTest" id="singlePageApp1">
      <xe:appPage pageName="dateTest" resetContent="true" id="appPage1">
        <xc:ccdateTest></xc:ccdateTest>
      </xe:appPage>
  </xe:singlePageApp>
</xp:view>
```

Custom control code (ccdateTest.xsp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view id="view1" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="dateTest">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:panel xp:key="actionFacet"/>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:djxmHeading>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1">
        <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

And in the xsp properties of the application:

[image: application xsp properties]

From your screenshot it looks like one of two things:

1. you are missing the mobile theme override in your xsp.properties (see my screenshot above)
2. or you've not set the mobile theme prefix correctly. It should be "m_" to match the name of your mobile xpages

Comment: Brian, please add the code of your example app to your answer :-)

Comment: Hi, I have use this with the same code, same Notes version (Notes 9.0.1 FP4) and Extension library (R14) but it is not showing correctly as specified in blue mix example. I had provided screen shot for the output on title.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like one of two things: 1. you are missing the mobile theme override  (see my screenshot above), 2. or you've not set the mobile theme prefix  correctly. It should be "m_" to match the name of your mobile xpages

Comment: Thanks for your response Brain. But I am using the same mobile theme and also using the same "m_" prefix. You can see it in my screen shot URL.

Comment: Are you testing on a domino server or using local web preview in the Notes Client? local web preview may not be 100% reliable for testing. For instance, when you install Extlib to Client/Designer, it does not install it for the local web preview server. There is a manual step needed to add it for preview